# How to work on open-source dependencies with incompatible editor settings in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, indentation

My project depends on two open-source libraries. Unfortunately both are a little under-developed and require constant contributions from me. What’s worse, though, is that one of them indents with three spaces and the other with four.

Is there anything at all I can do to avoid going crazy? I can’t realistically reformat either of these, since that would make it impossible for me to merge their future changes - let alone have my own patches accepted back. I can’t switch my tab width setting every time I tab between two files, either - not manually, anyway.

How do people deal with this situation in Visual Studio? Is there any improvement on the horizon?

Comment: Mwahaha, you’re totally fu... hang on, I have the same problem. Ffffuuuuuuuu